# For Android Junit Test Case, while adding package in src, In Gen i am getting package.test.test?

Tags: android, robotium

Test app - Original App which need to be tested..

Sample app - which I am creating to call the package of test app..

1. I am having .apk (which is in beta version i.e it is our application's apk) which did not go to Android Market.can i use robotium for testing the test environment apk or only the android market apk? I dont have the source code.
2. While creating app, do I need to go for android project or junit test case?
3. While creating project in eclipse, when I add package for my sample app (from that app I will call my test app’s package), in the gen [Generated java files] folder I am getting the name of the package is [package.test.test]. Is it right behavior?
4. I have debug.keystore for my test app. I have imported through this debug,keystor through preferences à android à Build path..So my test app and sample app both having same signature?

Regards,

Chandra

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read the Robotium FAQ and Setup documents.  They lay out everything very clearly and make it easy to get up and running within an hour.
[Main Robotium Page](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) 
[Robotium Wiki and Tutorials](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/w/list)